# htaccess map url to new url and throw 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to show http://www.domain.com/thread-category/subdomain/ when user requests http://subdomain.domain.com without changing url in address bar.

However, I don't want duplicate content, so when user / google bot requests http://www.domain.com/thread-category/subdomain/ I want to throw 404-not found error.

This is my code that is causing an infinite redirect loop

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Hide url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /thread-category/([^\?\ ]*)/
RewriteRule . - [R=404,NC,L]


# Show /thread-category/subdomain/ for 'subdomain.domain.com'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/thread-category/%1/$1 [P]
```

Basically I'm redirecting A to B and B to A and so on.. Basically I need a way to detect if that url is being accessed by htaccess or is being requested by somebody else... I tried with something like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^(.*)$
```

but it didn't work.

I've been searching but I couldn't find the way to fix it. What is the best way to stop this infinite redirect loop?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` in your first rule. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Hide url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /thread-category/([^\?\ ]*)/
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]

# Show /thread-category/subdomain/ for 'subdomain.domain.com'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/thread-category/%1/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: I also tried something like that but it didn't work... When trying to access using subdomain.domain.com I get "The requested URL /thread-category/science/ was not found on this server." - 404 not found. I don't know what may be causing this error... Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: First 404 rule will only impact `www.domain.com` due to this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]` condition. What URL did you enter in your browser and are there more rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: I've commented all the other rules just to be sure they're not interfering with these. Accessing both urls (subdomain.domain.com) and (www.domain.com/thread-category/subdomain/) I get 404 Not Found error. It's even worst that I'm on a shared environment and I can't access to log files to see what's going on... Aditionally it says: "500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request".

Comment: Comment out 3 lines below `Hide url` and see if 404/500 goes away for `www.domain.com/thread-category/subdomain/`

Comment: Using only the second rule I get 404 Not found - "The requested URL /thread-category/science/ was not found on this server." But if I enable wordpress multisite htaccess rules: [http://pastebin.com/uDy2G9x8](http://pastebin.com/uDy2G9x8)
It works fine.

Comment: That was your earlier rule and I didn't change anything in that.

Comment: Yes you definitely need last rule to write everything to `index.php`. Keep this suggested 404 before all other rules to make it work.

Comment: Yes... that's what I'm doing [http://pastebin.com/h73jnAP2](http://pastebin.com/h73jnAP2). It is still showing 404 for both urls... It's weird. I'll try to contact hosting to see what the 500 error says. Thanks for your time.